# Building a 360 degree interface for Android Application

Tags: android, virtual-reality, 360-degrees

What are the ways and tool to build a 360 degree interface for android applications. By 360 interface I mean a user interface with buttons and interface items embedded in a 360 degree spherical/cubical space. Users can either use their gyroscope/accelerometer to pan around like they do with a 360 video/image and if the device is not supported they can use the touch to pan and zoom. Can it be done in Android Studio or a something like Unity will be required. What is the best way to implement such an interface?

Comment: This is way too broad for SO, but the quick answer is Unity. You could do that in android studio and cardboard sdk, but unity will be so much easier.